# Automatically fetching a specific page in a livegrid smartgwt

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt-rpc

I have a live grid of records (datasource bounded), which are contacts.
The live grid is paged.
I have a problem where i have to show a searched record as selected in this livegrid.
On googling i found the API scrollToRow in listgrid.
Also it was documented somewhere, that scrollToRow works only after the record is drawn.

The issue is, if some one searches for a record which has not been fetched in the livegrid,and hence not drawn; scrollToRow will not work.
Is there any solution to fetch a specific page in livegrid or to keep fetching records in the grid till desired record is fetched.